# If I have: (apply f '(x1 x2 x3 .... xn)) and I'd like to change it to a macro expansion

Tags: scheme

I have `(apply f  '(x1 x2 x3 .... xn))`, and I'd like to change it to a macro expansion: `(f x1 x2 x3...xn)`. What kind of problems can occur?

Comment: You have not accepted any of your other 8 question. Were none of them the correct answer to your question? If (some of them) were, please take the time to go through them and accept those correct answers (just tick the 'V'-like icon next to the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just converting

```
(define (my-apply f args)
   (apply f args))
```

to

```
(define-macro (my-other-apply f args)
   `(,f ,@args))
```

then it seems to be simple enough. The biggest pitfall in this situation is that you'd have to remember not to quote the list you pass to the macro.

```
>(my-apply + '(1 2 3))
>6

>(my-other-apply + '(1 2 3))
>ERROR syntax-error: "(+ quote 1 2 3)"

>(my-other-apply + (1 2 3))
>6
```